# My layout inflater to add a custom view to my Linear Layout isnt working

Tags: java, android

So I am trying to create a custom view inside of a Linear Layout using layout inflater. I have never done this before, so please forgive me if I made a silly mistake. This is for a task app I am working on...

```
String subtaskName = getIntent().getStringExtra("subtaskName");
        boolean priHigh = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("priHigh", false);
        boolean priMed = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("priMed", false);
        boolean priLow = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("priLow", false);
        boolean timeMore = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("timeMore", false);
        boolean timeMed = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("timeMed", false);
        boolean timeLess = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("timeLess", false);


        for (int i = 0; i <=15; i++)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.subtask_item, subtaskLinLay, false);

            TextView subName = rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvSubtaskName);
            ImageView ivPri = rowView.findViewById(R.id.ivPri);
            ImageView ivTime = rowView.findViewById(R.id.ivTime);
            rowView.setId(i);

            subName.setText(subtaskName);

            if (priHigh)
            {
                ivPri.setImageResource(R.drawable.priority_high);
            }
            if (priMed)
            {
                ivPri.setImageResource(R.drawable.priority_med);
            }
            if (priLow)
            {
                ivPri.setImageResource(R.drawable.priority_low);
            }

            if (timeMore)
            {
                ivTime.setImageResource(R.drawable.time_symbol_more);
            }
            if (timeMed)
            {
                ivTime.setImageResource(R.drawable.time_symbol_med);
            }
            if (timeLess)
            {
                ivTime.setImageResource(R.drawable.time_symbol_less);
            }

            


        }
```

Comment: you didn't tell about any problems or errors , please provide more information

Comment: Apologies. The issue is that nothing happens when I press the required button. This code doesn't get executed.

Comment: i don't see any button in above code , please go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Note, that you should prefer to use `RecyclerView` to display lists.

Solution for this code:

```java
 // "this" is Context here
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

// the last arg should be true (attach to parent)
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.subtask_item, subtaskLinLay, true);
```

Comment: Okay. I'll try and see what I can do with a recyclerview.